# QT C++ Scroll Issues

Tags: c++, qt

I have an issue in locking a widget's contents to a scroll-area.
I think the best way to describe is in the pictures attached.
Picture 'a' is normal operation without a scroll area
Picture 'b' is when I attempt to add a scroll area to the widget.
The scroll- area appears but the text is not contained within.

The scroll-area is its own seperate entity with the content appearing away from it.

This is the code which I have placed in my widget:

```cpp
    QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
    scrollArea->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    scrollArea->setVisible(true);
    scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    scrollArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    scrollArea->setWidget(this);
    scrollArea->setGeometry(680, 250, 560, 440);
    scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Light);
```

Any ideas?

Picture a :

[image]

Picture b :

[image]

Here is the call to the custom child widget from the main GUI:

```
subalerPane = new subalertsPane(mstrWnd);
        subalerPane->setObjectName(subalertspane_params._name);
        subalerPane->setGeometry(QRect(subalertspane_params._x, subalertspane_params._y, subalertspane_params._w, subalertspane_params._h));
        subalerPane->setPixmaps(QPixmap(subalertspane_params._normalImageDm), QPixmap(subalertspane_params._normalImageNm), QPixmap(subalertspane_params._minimisedImageDm), QPixmap(subalertspane_params._minimisedImageNm));
        subalerPane->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        subalerPane->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
        subalerPane->setState(subalertspane_params._defaultState);
        subalerPane->setUIMode(subalertspane_params._defaultUIMode);
        subalerPane->setVisible(true);
        subalerPane->raise();
```

Here is the subalertsPane cpp file:

```
subalertsPane::subalertsPane(QWidget *parent) :QLabel(parent)
{   
    subalertsPane::state=bsNormal;                                              
subalertsPane::pressable=true;                                              
subalertsPane::uiMode=bdnDay;                                               

    connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotClicked()));        
    connect(this, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(slotReleased()));      

    statbutts[0] = new statusButton(this);
    statbutts[1] = new statusButton(this);
    statbutts[2] = new statusButton(this);
    statbutts[3] = new statusButton(this);
    statbutts[4] = new statusButton(this);
    statbutts[5] = new statusButton(this);
    statbutts[6] = new statusButton(this);
    statbutts[7] = new statusButton(this);
    statbutts[8] = new statusButton(this);
    statbutts[9] = new statusButton(this);
    statbutts[10] = new statusButton(this);


    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        statbutts[i]->fadeIn();
        statbutts[i]->setVisible(false);
    }

    QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
    scrollArea->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);


    scrollArea->setVisible(true);
    scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    scrollArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    scrollArea->setWidget(this);
    scrollArea->setGeometry(680, 250, 560, 440);
    scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Light);

}
```

Comment: You need to provide more of your code. That snippet tells us nothing much, except the `setWidget(this)` is clearly suspicious.

Comment: Enhanced the amount of code a bit there, thanks

Comment: Yea you probably need to get some QLayouts involved somehow (unless you're just not showing that part).  `scrollArea->setGeometry(680, 250, 560, 440);` is doing exactly what you told it to, and positioning the scroll area at 680x250 in relation to its parent (which is the top-level window since you don't set one).  It's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish, so it's hard to provide any concrete example. But that scroll area thing looks wrong, typically you create the scroll area and then place your widget into it, not have a widget place itself into a SA it creates... that seem weird.

Comment: If I create the scroll area prior to the widget I get the scrollarea without the content added to it...wierd.....https://ibb.co/34Q8BPH

Answer (score 1):

`QScrollArea::setWidget()` is used for setting a widget inside the scroll area with the the content. 
Example: if you want a QLabel with a text inside the scroll area - scrollArea->setWidget(qLabel);
Then add the scroll area to a layout of the view

```
  auto *scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
  scrollArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
  scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
  scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);

  auto *buttonsWidget = new QGroupBox(scrollArea);
  scrollArea->setWidget(buttonsWidget);
  auto *comboboxesLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
  buttonsWidget->setLayout(comboboxesLayout);

 mainLayout->addWidget(scrollArea);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try and use the function addWidget it says class "QWidget" has no member "addWidget"

Comment: You should be adding the widget to a QLayout.  In general, using layouts simplifies things so that when the containing window/widget changes sizes, the stuff in the window changes sizes also.

Comment: Yes, u can use addWidget() on a layout. Take your main widget, set a layout on it and then you can add child widgets to the main widget by adding them to the layout